# Installshield 2010: Can we execute OnInstalled Feature events during major upgrade?

Tags: installshield, major-upgrade

I have a setup project created with Installshield 2010, I want to create a major upgrade in Patch Design, for this:

- I changed the product version
- I changed the prouct code
- Added a row in Upgrade table
- Changed the package code
- msi arguments line: REINSTALLMODE=amus REINSTALL=ALL IS_MAJOR_UPGRADE=1

The files are being copied as expected but I noticed that when upgrading the features events I created in OnInstalled event are not being executed? Is there a way to male these functions execute even in the upgrade as the features are being reinstalled?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Kind Regards,
Imen

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem, in the OnResumeUIBefore(), I added the following:

```
    if( nMediaFlags & MEDIA_FLAG_FORMAT_DIFFERENTIAL ) then
        // Differential installs patch media.
        FeaturePatch();
    else
        // Update reinstalls (updates) all features in media.
        FeatureReinstall();
    endif;
```

And now it is OK,

Imen